# How to change color of helpText R Shiny

Tags: html, css, r, shiny

I need to change the color of my helpText in Shiny.  I'm using the same method I use to do the same for many other kinds of text, but it isn't working for this.  Here's the snippet of code I've tried to get to work, including failed tries commented out.  Any ideas would be greatly appreciated.

```
#tagList(
  # tags$style(HTML(".help-block a {color: black;}")),
  tags$style('#assignFlagHelpText .help-block a {color: black}'), 
    div(id = 'assignFlagHelpText',
      helpText('For grouped variables that depend on 1 sensor (i.e., wind speed/direction), 
                if one variable is bad, they likely all are.  In that case, use this button.')
),
#),
```

EDIT:  I've looked at the question and answer selected below, but either it won't work for me, or I don't know enough to modify it correctly for my purposes.  I've tried several ways.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Change font and color in helpText()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59292157/change-font-and-color-in-helptext)

Comment: I looked at that question and answer, but it doesn't help me because I don't know how to modify what I have to what they're doing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`helpText` in sidebar, header or body works fine.  Try this.

```
library(shiny)
library(shinydashboard)
library(shinydashboardPlus)

  ui = dashboardPagePlus(
    tags$head(
      tags$style(HTML(".help-block a {color: red !important;}")),
    ),

    
    header = dashboardHeaderPlus(
      left_menu = tagList(
        
        helpText(a('For grouped variables that depend on 1 sensor (i.e., wind speed/direction),
                if one variable is bad, they likely all are.  In that case, use this button.'))
      )
    ),
    sidebar = dashboardSidebar(
      helpText(a('For grouped variables that depend on 1 sensor (i.e., wind speed/direction),
                if one variable is bad, they likely all are.  In that case, use this button.'))
    ),
    body = dashboardBody(
      helpText(a('For grouped variables that depend on 1 sensor (i.e., wind speed/direction),
                if one variable is bad, they likely all are.  In that case, use this button.'))
    ),
  )
  server = function(input, output) { }
  shinyApp(ui,server)
```

[image: output]

Comment: This helpText is inside a wellPanel.  What would the syntax be for that?  Sorry if this is obvious, but for me it is not.  Thank you.

Comment: I finally figured out where things go.  Thank you.

Comment: Just wrap the helpText in wellPanel.  I tested it and it works.